# Why do I get a `Elixir.ModuleName.function is undefined!` error unless I run `mix clean`

Tags: elixir, beam

I’m having an unusual problem that I haven’t been able to search out an answer for. I’m using a library (libcluster) that allows you to define a function to use in the config file. So in my umbrella project, in a `config/def.exs` file I have:

`config libcluster: connect: {Module.Name, :function, args}` in `dev.exs`

Then there is a `lib/module/name.ex` with a function 
`def function(arg), do: <some code>`

`mix run` will run the code the first time. However, if I run the code again, I get an error:

`** (RuntimeError) Elixir.Module.Name.function/1 is undefined!`

If I run `mix clean` and then `mix run` everything works again. Why do I have to clean the code before I run the code in order to have the runtime see the function?

Comment: Does the application where you put the MFA (module/function/args) option specify the application where this module is defined as a dependency in its mix.exs? I.e. when application A defines module M, and application B uses this module in its config, application B should have a dependency to application A in its mix.exs to ensure proper compilation order.

Comment: It does. However, we found that if we reference Module.Name in the Application.Start method, this problem disappears.